# ssrs with custom rows in Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have this raw data:
[image]

In the data the "Act" is actual number, "Fct" are forecasted, and I have to create a row called "Var" to calculate (Act-Fct).  The "Cum" is the accumulated variance.
The "Prev" refers to the previous year data and the"VarYOY" refers to the variance year over year (Prev-Act).

I am not sure how to get the "Var", "Cum" and "VarYOY" rows into the matrix.  Any guidance or a sample solution would be what I'm looking for.[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'get the "Var", "Cum" and "VarYOY" rows into the matrix?  Do you mean make them groupings horizontally or vertically or something else?  They are showing so I do not know what you mean without more information of 'into the matrix'.

Comment: It seems like you have a lot of questions here - I would recommend breaking the issues down and asking one at a time. Also, provide sample data that can be copied/pasted instead of screenshots. One piece of advice looking at your dataset - it would be easier if you had one row per *custid/yearmo* with both the actual and forecast values. If you can pivot up your rows when generating the dataset it would prevent a lot of unnecessary aggregation in the report.

Comment: Thanks, I will break it down and ask separately.